# User permission for laravel project - apache2

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have laravel project stored in /var/www/html/laravel3

I have a problem when I add this:

```
sudo chown -R myUserName:myUserName /var/www/html/laravel3
```

I can upload files to laravel3 folder but browser-users cant access to project

so I do:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/laravel3
```

and now user can access to project data but I cant upload files to folder...

as I see on sFTP (cyberduck) permission is changed from 1000 to 33 , but both case is not goo for me..

So how to configure permission so user can access project but also allow me to upload files?

Comment: `but I can't upload files to folder...` which folder and how it is supposed to be uploaded?

Comment: I cant upload via sFTP cyberduck , also I cant list folder laravel3 ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have wrong permissions set. So I'm going to tell you all steps you need:

1- Change permission of all directories to 755 (drwxr-xr-x):

```
chmod 755 /var/www/html/laravel3; find /var/www/html/laravel3 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

2- All files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):

```
find /var/www/html/laravel3 -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

3- Take care of `storage` and `cache` directories owners and groups:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/laravel3/storage /var/www/html/laravel3/bootstrap/cache
```

4- Their permissions:

```
chmod -R ug=rwx /var/www/html/laravel3/storage /var/www/html/laravel3/bootstrap/cache
```

5- Add your username to Apache's group so that later you don't encounter problems in reading files:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data this-is-your-username
```

6- Congratulations!